# MVC Code First Approach for Production Environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am very new in MVC and don't have live project working experience.

My question is how we will set up a database for a website with lots of application in CF approach in Production?

For smaller application like MusicStore(Sample project for MVC 4) the database is placed at App_Data folder but in case of huge project what will be the scenario?

Comment: kindly explain your question in more clear manner

Comment: You use a proper database server instead of the database file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use Code First then use migrations, it should help not remove any existing data. As Jasen mentioned use a real db server and not a db file. A lot of demos/tutorials use db files as it's easily portable, but really don't use them in a real system.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591621.aspx) may help

Comment: Ok i got my answer..Now correct my understanding if i am wrong@ matt_lethargic

The database files got saved in App_data folder in sample project because sql server is by default installed in VS but in case of real system we have to use migration for our model classes to be used as a database table in real db server.

Comment: You don't have to use Migrations with a SQL Server, but if you're using code first Migrations help you over standard code first.